# Kafka Stream API: KStream to KGroupedStream to KTable to KStream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka readings stream to which I check if a certain threshold is exceeded. I only want to propagate an alert if it is exceeded for the first time. To achieve this, I first calculate the new state, group the new states in a KGroupedStream. Then reduce to a KTable where I check if the state changed (keep a boolean) and change to changelog stream and filter on the records where the state changed.

My theory was that this should work, however not each state change is propagated to the changelog stream, but only once in a while the changelog stream seems to be updated (can't really see a pattern). Anyone know why this, or even better how I can solve this issue?

Simplified example:

```
KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder.stream("input");
KStream<String, String> outputStream = inputStream
  .groupByKey()
  .reduce((previousValue, newValue) -> newValue)
  .toStream();
outputStream.to("output");
```

In this case I would expect that each new incoming value would be put on the output stream. However this is not the case, only once in a while a value is put on the output stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you have the cache buffering enabled (it's by default). 
Try to configure the following properties on your Streams configuration.

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
```